# Unity Firebase on IOS lFirebaseCore is not found error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

i am importing my unity project to xcode to compile. I imported Firebase SDK in unity and exported for ios. But on build i am getting the following error.

```
ld: library not found for -lFirebaseCore
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have the cocoapods. File looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.24.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.24.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '6.24.0'
end
```

So it looks everything is imported but i also can not find lFirebaseCore file anywhere myself.

I am fighting with it for a week now. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal window
Go to project folder and run this
"pod update"